# Ruby each block next when exception or error is raised

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following method in my rake task.

```
def call
  orders = Spree::Order.complete.where('completed_at >= :last_day', last_day: Time.now - 30.days)
  orders.each do |order|
    order_tracking = order.shipments.first.tracking
    next if order_tracking.nil?
    shipment = order.shipments.first
    results = fedex.track(tracking_number: order_tracking)
    tracking_info = results.first
    status = tracking_info.status.to_s
    delivery_date = tracking_info.delivery_at
    shipment.is_delivered = delivered?(status)
    shipment.date_delivered = delivery_date
    shipment.save
    puts "-> Shipping status was updated for #{order.number}"
  end
end
```

If there is an order with no tracking number I skipping it with `next` on line 5.

My question: How would I do `next` if a tracking number is invalid and the following error is raised:

```
Fedex::RateError: Invalid tracking number.
```

Ideally I would like to change line 5 to:

```
next if order_tracking.nil? || order_tracking.raised(Fedex::RateError) # something like that
```

Thank you in advance.

Also RateError is raised here:

```
def process_request
  api_response = self.class.post(api_url, :body => build_xml)
  puts api_response if @debug == true
  response = parse_response(api_response)

  if success?(response)
    options = response[:track_reply][:track_details]

    if response[:track_reply][:duplicate_waybill].downcase == 'true'
      shipments = []
      [options].flatten.map do |details|
      options = {:tracking_number => @package_id, :uuid => details[:tracking_number_unique_identifier]}
      shipments << Request::TrackingInformation.new(@credentials, options).process_request
      end
      shipments.flatten
    else
      [options].flatten.map do |details|
        Fedex::TrackingInformation.new(details)
      end
    end
  else
    error_message = if response[:track_reply]
                      response[:track_reply][:notifications][:message]
                    else
                      "#{api_response["Fault"]["detail"]["fault"]["reason"]}\n--#{api_response["Fault"]["detail"]["fault"]["details"]["ValidationFailureDetail"]["message"].join("\n--")}"
                    end rescue $1
    raise RateError, error_message
  end
end
```

Comment: I think you are going to need a `begin\rescue` block to handle this e.g. `begin; YOUR LOOP CODE HERE; rescue Fedex::RateError => e; #maybe log the error; next; end`

Comment: No worries, solved it. thanks for the edit and help.

Answer (score 1):

added:

```
private

def fedex_track(tracking)
  fedex.track(tracking_number: tracking)
end
```

And changed `results` on line 7 to:

```
results = fedex_track(order_tracking) rescue next
```

Comment: I agree, maybe a little cleaner, but that's subjective.

Comment: Also I would suggest only rescuing the `Fedex::RateError` right now you are rescuing every error which is generally considered a bad idea and makes debugging far more difficult.

Comment: Point noted, I prefer using `next` for all errors given that I'm calling the method on a rake task, instead of aborting the task and not updating the following  orders. I'll keep that in mind during debugging, Thank you @engineersmnky